# Kendo DatePicker culture not working correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, culture, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to localize Kendo Datepicker to my culture "is-IS" but for some reason it doesn´t work correctly.  This is code example:

```
$("#RegisterDatePicker").kendoDatePicker({
    start: "month",
    culture: "is-IS",
    value: new Date(),
    format: "dd.MMMM yyyy",
    events: {
        change: "registerDatePicker_OnChange"
    }
});
```

The culture seems to revert to its default localization "en-US".  I know this culture should work with Datepicker because whenever I declare the Datepicker within the Razor engine it **renders correctly**.  Here´s a code example from Razor:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
  .Name("RegisterDatePicker")
  .Start(CalendarView.Month)
  .Value(DateTime.Now)
  .Format("dd.MMMM yyyy")
  .Events(e => e.Change("registerDatePicker_OnChange"))
  .Culture("is-IS")
)
```

Can anyone point out whats wrong with the script declaration of my Datepicker?

Comment: Have you included the correct culture script (kendo.culture.is-IS.min.js) in your page?

Comment: You were right @nemesv, I didn´t include the culture script.  Basic fail on my part, thank you.  (I upped you for your comment since I can´t up any answer)  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to the [Kendo Globalization](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/globalization/overview) work correctly you need to include the correct additional culture scripts after you have included the Kendo scripts.

So in you case you need the to include the `kendo.culture.is-IS.js` script:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="kendo.culture.is-IS.js"></script>
```