# Kendo DatePicker Globalization Binding Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, globalization, kendo-datepicker

I have an asp.net MVC application with "es-MX" culture. Here's what I have in my web.config file:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="es-MX" culture="es-MX"></globalization>
```

And, here's what I have in my _Layout page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //set current to the "es-MX" culture script
        kendo.culture("es-MX");
    })
</script>
```

I have a Kendo DatePicker like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.StartDate)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "input-field" })
)
```

When I post back the form to my controller, the `StartDate` field is null.

Here's the response I get from the server:

> "Errors":{"StartDate":{"errors":["The value \u002707/10/2016 12:00:00
>   a. m.\u0027 is not valid for Fecha de Inicio."]}}

By the way, the Accept-Language of the request that is sent to the server is "en-US", which I find strange.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to use a custom model binder for DateTime, like this:

```
public class DateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.AttemptedValue))
            return null;

        DateTime dateTime;
        var isDate = DateTime.TryParse(value.AttemptedValue, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, 
            DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);

        if (!isDate)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "La fecha es válido.");
            return DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

        return dateTime;
    }
}
```

But, it looks like the problem is with the time part of the date passed to the controller. The value `07/10/2016 12:00:00 a. m.` is not recognized as a date by neither the "es-MX" nor the "en-US" culture.

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to culture because 07/10/2016 should be a validate date in both es-MX (Oct. 7) and en-US (July 10)

Comment: @AndrésNava-.NET, I know, but I don't have any problem when I remove the es-MX culture from the web.config file and the _Layout page. However, if I just change the culture of the DatePicker to en-US, it still won't bind.

Comment: @AndrésNava-.NET, please see my update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured what the issue was. According to the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/globalization#use-the-culture-helper), the Kendo UI culture scripts are generated based on the **Windows 8** formats. I'm using Windows 7. So, I'll have to put this Culture Helper on top of the page to make sure the scripts are generated based on the current .NET or specified culture:

```
@Html.Kendo().Culture()
```

Without this helper, the dates posted to the server will be like `07/10/2016 12:00:00 a. m.` (note the space between a. and m.), and that's my MVC is not able to bind them. After using the helper, the dates will be like `07/10/2016 12:00:00 a.m.` (without the space).

Answer (score 0):

On first sight, your error message tells invalid date format was passed to model:

> "Errors":{"StartDate":{"errors":["The value \u002707/10/2016 12:00:00
>   a. m.\u0027 is not valid for Fecha de Inicio."]}}

By considering Unicode translation from provided JSON format, the message can be fetched as

> "Errors":{"StartDate":{"errors":["The value '07/10/2016 12:00:00 a.
>   m.' is not valid for Fecha de Inicio."]}}

`'07/10/2016 12:00:00 a. m.'` indicates date format passed as a string instead of a recognizable DateTime value, hence your `model.StartDate` returns null since the time part with AM/PM state is not a valid `DateTime` or `Nullable<DateTime>` value.

Try setting the globalization script into your view:

```
@section HeadContent 
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cultures/kendo.culture.es-MX.min.js")"></script>
}
```

or layout page:

```
<head>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cultures/kendo.culture.es-MX.min.js")"></script>
</head>
```

NB: Change `~/Scripts/cultures/` into your Kendo JS directory path.

If attempt(s) above still won't work, set display format string on `DatePickerFor`:

```
@{
    Culture = "es-MX";
}

@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.StartDate)
    .Name("StartDate")
    .Culture("es-MX")
    .Format("dd/MM/yyyy")
    .ParseFormats(new String[] { "dd/MM/yyyy" })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "input-field" })
)
```

or by adding custom rule for date input as this (adapted from Edin Mahmutovic's answer in [How to valid date format dd.MM.yyyy KENDO MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33667588/how-to-valid-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-kendo-mvc)):

```
kendo.ui.validator.rules.mvcdate = function (input) {
    if ($(input.attr('name')) === 'StartDate') {
        return input.val() === "" || kendo.parseDate(input.val(), "dd/MM/yyyy") !== null;
    }
    return true;
}
```

AFAIK, when a specific date format string is not being set by `Format` method, it uses default format shown on this example: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/index.

Related problems:

[Kendo datepicker acting weired for different computers on two different timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253430/kendo-datepicker-acting-weired-for-different-computers-on-two-different-timezone)

[Kendo DatePicker culture not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20872035/kendo-datepicker-culture-not-working-correctly)

http://www.telerik.com/forums/wrong-format

Globalization reference: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/globalization

Comment: I don't have any problem with displaying the date in the right format. The problem is with the date that is posted to the server. I've already found what the problem was. Check my answer.